# How to generate a rule to tell that this simple facts go both ways?

Tags: prolog

So I have a couple of facts:

```
%bridge(Name,From,To).
bridge(a,1,2).
bridge(b,1,2).
bridge(c,2,3).
bridge(d,3,4).
```

Edit:changed to atoms

So this reads like "bridge A crosses from zone 1 to zone 2". This is simple. However, the inverse is also true. Bridge A crosses from zone 2 to zone 1. That's why I thought:

```
bridge(B,S,E):- bridge(B,E,S).
```

Thing is, this messes up my program because whenever swi-prolog can't find a match for a bridge, it will keep using the bridge rule to invert it's parameters over and over again. Is there any way to stop this? Or is there any other way to create a simple rule? My program works flawlessly if I add every other fact (bridge(A,2,1), bridge(C,3,2), etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that you seem to be using variables where you meant to use atoms to identify bridges.

As to your question: You can easily solve this by adding the additional required facts, for example:

```
bridge(a, 1, 2).
bridge(a, 2, 1).

bridge(b, 1, 2).
bridge(b, 2, 1).

etc.
```

However, as you already seem to have noticed intuitively, this is clearly redundant and you can refactor it with an auxiliary predicate, say for example `bridge_/2`, that consists of two clauses:

```
bridge(B, X, Y) :- bridge_(B, X, Y).
brigde(B, X, Y) :- bridge_(B, Y, X).

bridge_(a, 1, 2).
bridge_(b, 2, 1).
bridge_(c, 2, 3).
etc.
```

Comment: As my question says, I already solved it by adding the additional facts. However, the auxiliar predicate is really neat!!!

Answer (score 1):

Prolog offers a way to process each clause read, *before* asserting it, by means of [term_expansion](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_expansion/2)/2. Should work this way:

```
term_expansion(bridge(K,A,B), bridge(K,A,B)) :- assertz(bridge(K,B,A)).
```

That is, it 'returns' the unchanged term read, and add a term with swapped 'connections'.
Beware that could be difficult to get debug your transformed source with the graphical tracer...

*edit* my answer was a bit superficial, I'm trying to debug it...

*edit* thanks to Paulo hint, here is something working...

```
:- module(bridge, [bridge/3]).

term_expansion(bridge(K,A,B), [bridge(K,A,B),bridge(K,B,A)]).

bridge(a,1,2).
bridge(b,1,2).
bridge(c,2,3).
bridge(d,3,4).
```

Comment: But that requires making `bridge/3` a dynamic predicate. No need of you rewrite the `term_expansion/2` clause as `term_expansion(bridge(K,A,B), [bridge(K,A,B), bridge(K,B,A)]).`.

Comment: @PauloMoura: thanks so much for the hint about the list ! I was having hard time debugging it..